# Restrict graphic tablet to primary display

Tags: x11, manjaro, tablet

I have a Huion DWH69 graphic tablet with Manjaro Linux installed.

I have two displays connected.

It seems like to work out of the box, but the problem is that I want to bound the surface to the limits of the primary monitor.

At the moment, the horizontal movements are very fast since it is a small tablet but a huge area of display.

How can I configure that? I guess I have to touch the X-Server in some way, but I don't know how.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *primary monitor* in this context.  It sounds like you have them set up as one large display which the mouse pointer just moves across.

Answer (score 13):

also check out bebop's answer here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/839161/limit-a-graphics-tablet-to-one-monitor
its a longer version with some extras. For the QUICK AND DIRTY VERSION:

Found this, it fixed my issue which sounded similar to yours.
https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=139&t=125532

This is the code for HUION New 1060 for example: HID 256c:006e Pad
First type:

```
xinput  # get the IDs for all relevant pieces of my tablet.
```

blah blah: HID 256c:006e Pad id=17
there might/should be two devices, Pad and Pen. Then do:

```
xrandr  # get the names of my displays
```

look for the ones showing 'connected' like HDMI-A-0 connected
and maybe DisplayPort-2 connected

Then you tell xinput to stick the id's to the screen you want Krita or Photoshop on, such as if you were using a HDMI port to main screen:

```
xinput map-to-output 13 HDMI-A-0
xinput map-to-output 14 HDMI-A-0
```

that was mine.
it resets after a reboot. thanks to that user timotimo!

Answer (score 3):

To add onto [JRRs response](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/439625/377345), I've found that after following his instructions, by running

```
xinput list-props [device id]
```

you can get the property "Coordinate Transformation Matrix", and then create a file at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/xx-tablet.conf` with the following:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier      "Tablet Screen Restriction"
        MatchProduct    "[device name]"
        Option          "Coordinate Transformation Matrix"      "output of xinput list-props [device id]"
EndSection
```

Doing this *should* make your config persist through reboots.

Answer (score 0):

My dual display system is set up so that windows can move smoothly between the dislays; i.e. the X server sees it as one large display with perhaps different resolutions on different parts.  From this perspective, what you're asking is to restrict pointer access to just one portion of the "display".  I'm pretty sure there is no way to do this.